# How do I list numbers -for example from 1 to 20- in a LOV item by using pl/SQL function? Return values are same as display values

Tags: loops, oracle-apex, lov

I'm trying to list numbers -for example from 1 to 20- in a LOV item by using a loop in a pl/SQL function. It must be possible but I haven't succeeded yet. Thanks for your precious helps.

Comment: Does it have to be a PL/SQL function rather than a SQL query?  You could certainly write a pipelined table function that returned 20 rows.  But a SQL query is going to involve a lot less code.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  If I create a table which is include two column, first for id and second for numbers then I can write an SQL query like this: select number d, id r from numbers; but I dont want to create a table for just numbers. I want to use loop or something like that.

Comment: You can write a SQL query that generates the numbers 1-20 without creating a `numbers` table.  Is that acceptable?  Or does it need to use PL/SQL?

Comment: Yes it is acceptable. Could you write it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do pl/sql, this can be achieved using the pseudo column `LEVEL` and the `CONNECT BY` clause in pure SQL. Very useful for selects like date lists, number lists, etc. For a list of numbers from 1 to 20 you could do this:

```
SELECT
  level  AS display_value,
  level  AS return_value
  FROM
  dual
CONNECT BY
  level <= 20
```

Comment: And some more explanation is here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/display-sequence-of-numbers-in-sql-using-level/#:~:text=LEVEL%20must%20be%20used%20with,database%20along%20with%20data%20dictionary.